# How do I convert a new Date() into the client's time?

Tags: javascript, date, time

I'm trying to get

```
date = new Date()
```

and then make it into a local time from the client, how would I go about doing that?

I would need the Date, in this format
Day[Mon,Tues, etc.], Day of the month[18], Month[Nov,etc.], Year, then the time in either a 24 hour format or a 12 hour format, seconds would be good.

I've tried using the getTimezoneOffset(), but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: when run in browser, `new Date` is client time based on users device time setting. Need to elaborate in more detail what you are trying to do

Comment: @charlietfl I thought it was from UTC... Interesting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates in JavaScript should always be in the format of the client computer.

If `toLocaleDateString` isn't working for you, I recommend **[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)**

Using `toLocaleDateString`:

```
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString());
```

Using Moment.js:

```
console.log(moment().format('llll'));
```

Comment: I think you meant date.toLocaleString(), not to mention your toLocaleDateString() returns a has no method... yet using the the date.toLocaleDateString() works for the date... I think I'll try the frame work, you might want to check the post.

Comment: @Loper324 `date.now()` returns a numeric version, not a date object which was causing the **has no method** error. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

By a "local time from the client" I assume that your server returns some time from, let's say, GMT-0 , and your client is at GMT-3.

Knowing your server timezone, you could do some trick to do the math using jsTimezoneDetect (http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/).

And regarding the statement "Dates in JavaScript should always be in the format of the client computer.", that's assuming you are using Javascript on the client side, while in fact, you could be using it on the server (nodes).

BTW, when you say "I'm trying to get date = new Date()" I'm assuming you're doing that on the server with nodejs, otherwise, both jasonscript and Loper324 are right, you are already in the client so that Date will be in the timezone of the client. Or were you referring just to the formatting?